# Uncheck radio button in Ionic 4

Tags: radio-button, ionic4

How can I uncheck a radio button or reset a radio group in Ionic 4?

This is not working (which used to work until Ionic 2):

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-list formControlName="listOptions">
      <ion-radio-group>

        <ion-item class="bgtransparent" [ngClass]="{'bgred': correctAnswerFirst}">
          <ion-radio value="answer1" (ionSelect)="processSelectedAnswer(1)"></ion-radio>
          <ion-label>{{answer1}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="bgtransparent" [ngClass]="{'bgred': correctAnswerSecond}">
          <ion-radio value="answer2" (ionSelect)="processSelectedAnswer(2)"></ion-radio>
          <ion-label>{{answer2}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="bgtransparent" [ngClass]="{'bgred': correctAnswerThird}">
          <ion-radio value="answer3" (ionSelect)="processSelectedAnswer(3)"></ion-radio>
          <ion-label>{{answer3}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="bgtransparent" [ngClass]="{'bgred': correctAnswerFourth}">
          <ion-radio value="answer4" (ionSelect)="processSelectedAnswer(4)"></ion-radio>
          <ion-label>{{answer4}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>

    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

.

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      listOptions: ['']
    });
```

So mainly this function does not work anymore:

```
this.myForm.controls.listOptions.reset();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your `formControl` be on the `ion-radio-group`?

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group formControlName="listOptions">
```